# CORS/JavaScript/Laravel: Sending request to Digital Ocean server and receiving data (Headers issues)

Tags: javascript, laravel, nginx

So, what I'm trying to do is use a Digital Ocean droplet as an api for an application hosted on a different server. Currently, I'm just developing so this server is from my localhost:3000.

On my client side code (JavaScript) I have:

```
  handleSendData = () => {
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest()
    request.open('POST', 'http://my-droplet-ip/api/create-image')
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8')
    request.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://my-droplet-ip')
    request.send(JSON.stringify(data-object))
  }
```

Finally, in my Laravel application (Laravel Framework 5.8.18) I have a route under `routes/api.php`:

```
Route::post('/create-image', 'CreateData');
```

And I have a controller `CreateData.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CreateImage extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Handle the incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function __invoke(Request $request)
    {
        return response('Hello World', 200)
            ->header('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    }
}
```

The problem is when I try to run this request, I get a CORS error:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://my-droplet-ip/api/create-image. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)

Under the networking tab I get a 404 not found and the Access header is not there in the response.

Any thoughts out there on this issue?

Comment: "Under the networking tab I get a 404 not found" — So the problem doesn't really have anything to do with CORS. You got the URL wrong. (Unless it is talking about the preflight OPTIONS request, in which case you might have forgotten to handle that at all, but you didn't quote the full error message or give all the details on the Network tab)

Comment: I strongly recommend https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors for CORS handling.

Answer (score -1):

There is a simple solution to this and it is ok for testing on you local machine.

You could just put in index file to allow cors, but I suggest you building middleware for this.

Here is a link it is explained really nice:)

https://medium.com/@petehouston/allow-cors-in-laravel-2b574c51d0c1

You can put also this in index.php

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
```

Hope it helps :D

Comment: Okay I tried using a middleware class as described but, I am still getting Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at <backend server> (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)

Comment: I removed everything from the nginx default config

Comment: Put this in index.php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");